# Props not pass in the route though pass it in the render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to pass the props in the route component, I know we cannot directly pass to that, so I used to render, but the props are still undefined in the child component.

```
import React from 'react';
//components
import Register from '../components/register/register';
import Login from "../components/login/login";
import  ForgetPassword from '../components/forget-password/forget-password';
//redux
import {store} from "../redux/store";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import actions from "../redux/authentication/actions";
//react-router
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Switch} from "react-router-dom";
//antd
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
//css
import '../global/_global.scss';

function Authentication(props) {
  console.log("PROPS", props)
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
      {/*switch-component will render first that matches the includes path*/}
      <Switch>
        <Route  path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route  exact  path='/' component={Login}  />
        <Route   path='/register'
          render={(props) => (
              <Register {...props} check={props.registerUser}  />
          )}
                   />
        <Route   path='/forget-password' component={ForgetPassword} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return state.reducers;
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Authentication);
```

Comment: try changing `render={(props) => (` to `render={() => (`

Comment: It's working. Thank you, but why it's not working if I do like that.

Comment: Because the props you are trying to pass are not coming from the `render` function but from the props you receive in the `Authentication` component.

Answer (score 0):

try using like this

```
 return (
    <Route
      render={routeProps => (
        
          <Component {...routeProps} />
       
      )}
    />
  );
```

instead of

```
return (
        <Route
          render={(routeProps) => (
            
              <Component {...routeProps} />
           
          )}
        />
      );
```

Comment: May I ask how this makes a difference? Leaving out the brackets is perfectly fine if there's just one argument as far as I know. I think the problem is reusing a name that has already been defined in the scope.